# Top right side page numbering

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want the numbers of pages to be placed at the top right side.
I try to do it like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

My text.

\end{document}
```

Numbers still remains like default - center of bottom. What do I wrong?

Comment: You didn't issue `\pagestyle{fancy}`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "fancy" settings are enforced only when `\pagestyle{fancy}` is issued:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

My text.

\end{document}
```

I've used the "modern" commands provided by `fancyhdr`, which are more flexible; with `\fancyhf{}` you void all fields at once and then you can fill them again as you wish.

Answer (score 10):

Try with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
 My text be here!!
\end{document}
```