# How to label all pagenumbers to TOC in fancy footer?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, fancyhdr

I want to have a reference from everypage to the first page of the document. 
I think the link can exist well in the pagenumber of every page back to the TOC (first page here). 
Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Is it the header or the footer?

Comment: the operating system is never going to be relevant here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

A `docstart\jobname` hypertarget is placed right at the start of `\begin{document}` and another hypertarget anchor is placed as `mytoc\jobname` at `\tableofconents`.

In `fancypagestyle{plain}` the footer definitions use `\hyperlink{docstart\jobname}{First page}}` etc.

Please mind the`\phantomsection` in front of the `\hypertarget` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hyperlink{docstart\jobname}{First page}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\hyperlink{mytoc\jobname}{\contentsname}}
}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\hypertarget{docstart\jobname}{}
\blindtext[10]
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{mytoc\jobname}{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Beginning Foo}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am thinknig here how to apply this approach when I have this macro in use: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludepdf\includepdf
\renewcommand{\includepdf}[4][]{%
  \oldincludepdf[pagecommand={‌​\thispagestyle{fancy‌​}},addtotoc={#4,section,1,#2,#3}, #1]{#2}}`. It calls there `fancy` but how to apply the specific `fancypagestyle` is a question mark for me.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Yes, but that was not in your question, was it? ;-)

Comment: No. - - I minimalised it with the target in my last comment. :) Now, scratching my head, but waiting now for your other answer in the other thread, because I think it can help.

Comment: I am trying to understand now the case better here after studying your proposal about *key-value interface* https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365684/13173