# How to make colorised linked pagenumbering of appended documents?

Tags: hyperref, color, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am trying to understand the last part of the answer, *Key-value interface*'s pagenumbering, in the thread [How to generate TOC by custom labels at appended documents' beginnings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365580/13173)
I would like to colorise the pagenumber to red and make a link to it, back to the first page of the document (ToC, for instance). 
I think `fancypagestyle` is not the optimal here in the thread [How to label all pagenumbers to TOC in fancy footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365588/13173) 
My proposal but sure how to apply them to the Christian's *Key-value interface*'s pagenumbering

- `\usepackage{xcolor}` so `{\color{red} pagenumber}`
- with a link to ToC, the following pseudocode, but not sure how to make an internal one here

  ```
  \href{some-how-link-to-1st-page-of-document}{{\color{red} pagenumber}}
  ```

Relevant part of Christian's code

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365580/13173
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for links in TOC
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56316/13173
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Werner, remove top margin border
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338919/13173
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\pdfpages@@includepdf\includepdf

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includepdf}{O{}mo}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueTF{#3}{% Is there a 3rd argument? Yes
    % Process the keys for the \includepdf first in order to get the value of 'pages=...' option
    % This is stored to \AM@pagestemp (see pdfpages.sty)
    \setkeys{pdfpages}{#1}%
    \SetupPdfInclude{label={label#2\AM@pagestemp},page={\AM@pagestemp}, heading={#2},#3}
    % Call the old command with the options for addtotoc
    \pdfpages@@includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},addtotoc={\retrieveoption{page},\retrieveoption{section},\retrieveoption{level},\retrieveoption{heading},\retrieveoption{label}},#1]{#2}
  }{% No, no 3rd. argument}
    \pdfpages@@includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},#1]{#2}
  }%
  \endgroup% Prevent leaking of key values to the next call of the command
}
\makeatother
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB

Comment: Are you after `\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you please give an example about that? - - `colorlinks` seems to be appropriate, also `linktocpage` but not sure where this link is going to be created.

Comment: Just add the line to a file which uses my answer  about the redefined `\includepdf` (which I added yesterday, I think)

Comment: linktocpage = link the page number displayed in the ToC to the relevant page instead of the section etc. name being a link -- the link anchor is the same, the difference is the page numbers are clickable now and the entries aren't

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, I think it is not what I want. I want to have links at pagenumber elsewhere than TOC, back to TOC, such that you can easily read the document and going back to TOC.

Comment: I think, your question is not related to the issue with the pdfpages...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, you seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `\hypersetup{linkcolor}{red}\hyperlink{mytoc\jobname}{\thepage}}` (whereas `red` is the default colour anyway for links)`

Since this occurs in a group, `\hypersetup` does not leak outside other than the local group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % for links in TOC
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\hyperlink{docstart\jobname}{First page}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\hyperlink{mytoc\jobname}{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{docstart\jobname}{}
\blindtext[10]
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{mytoc\jobname}{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\section{Beginning Foo}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

With `fancy` pagestyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % for links in TOC
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

% Now for fancy pagestyle
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\hyperlink{docstart\jobname}{First page}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\hyperlink{mytoc\jobname}{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{docstart\jobname}{}
\blindtext[10]
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{mytoc\jobname}{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\section{Beginning Foo}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Confirmed! Both approaches work with or without `pdfpages`. I disabled `first page` feature in a document where first page is the same as TOC. - - How can you make the red page number size bigger? I am thinking how to make the document for usable on tablets. - - I noticed that the location of the pagenumber raises up little by the approaches. Do you understand why? I think it is the only bug here. Maybe, this command `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` is overrun somehow.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: `\thepage` comes down to something like `\arabic{page}`, which is normal typesetting, so `\huge\thepage` inside the link will enlarge the pagenumber. You can use any of the font size switches there, i.e. \large etc. `\bfseries` is also possible

Comment: Some documentation about `\phantomsection` here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44091/13173

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: I see no raising in the position of the page number.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: You're trying to squeeze a full page of another document on a document with the same page size and still having header and footer -- this will cause problems. If possible you should strip the footer of the other documents (if they are LaTeX documents, this should be possible)