# How to align contents title in Portuguese documents?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, babel, tocloft

In Portuguese, the name of "Table of Contents" is "Sumário". So, I'd like to get the word "Sumário" in the center of the page.

I know how to put the title in the center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I also know how to replace "Table of Contents" by "Sumário":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

However, these two solutions does not work together. When using both, we obtain the word "Sumário", but not in the center.

What could I do?

**Remark:** I'm also using `\usepackage{tocloft}` and `\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}` for other purposes in the documment. So, they cannot be removed from the preamble (i.e. the solution have to be compatible with both).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you trying to follow ABNT rules?

Comment: @Joseph Exactly! And it's not easy in Latex. Fortunately, there are users who can help.

Comment: Pedro, there is a class (and another package) that do that already: try out `abntex2`, if it's an article, just do `\documentclass[article]{abntex2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply merging your solutions doesn't work because `babel` defers the definition of the section headers after the `\begin{document}`. You can overcome this by inserting the `\renewcommand{\contentsname}` *after* `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Sum\'ario\hfill\null}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

As remco pointed out in the comments, the redefinition of `\contentsname` happens when you switch the language, for example, with `\selectlanguage`. So after every language-switching command you have to re-reset the `\contentsname`.

Another alternative is to add the redefinitions to `\captionsbrazil`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Sum\'ario\hfill\null}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

This would make the new definition of `\contentsname` as the "default". But I don't know about the robustness of this, because the `\captions<language>` macro is supposed to have only the names of the headers...

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But that failed after changing the language with \selectlanguage (which seems to reset the `\contentsname`), so the redefinition(s) should be done just before the `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @remco Yes, the definitions are made when babel executes `\captions<language>`. And the language switching commands, like `\selectlanguage` do that. I'll add a note in my answer :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If I use fancyhdr to put the page number at top right (as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56320/110487)), the "sumário" goes to the left (not totally). Is there any solution?

Comment: @Pedro If you look carefully, the previous solution had `\hfill\bfseries\Large Contents\hfill` and a `\cftaftertoctitle` (which I suppose is inserted after the title) which was `\hfill`. This roughly translates to `\hfill Contents\hfill\hfill`, which makes the space on the right twice as large as the one on the left. Something was removing one of these `\hfill`s before you used `\pagestyle{fancy}`, and stopped. I changed the definition of `\contentsname` to contain both the `\hfill`s and removed the `\cftaftertoctitle` which was causing the difference.